# Timeline, inserting rows in SQL

Tags: timeline

My table 'Stops' looks like this:

Id  TimeStart  TimeFinished  StopType
1    06:00             07:00                      1
2   08:00             09:00                      2
3    10:00             11:00                      3

and so on...

The entries are different types of stops, planned, unplanned etc, defined by 'StopType'. Everything not within a timerange is 'production time', like between 07:00 and 08:00.
I want to make a timeline that includes the production time.

**Result:**
TimeStart   TimeFinished   StopType
06:00        07:00              1

07:00        08:00              5

08:00        09:00              2

09:00        10:00              5

10:00        11:00              3


where (StopType = 5) = production time

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Gustaf!  I think I can help but your question is a bit unclear.  When you say "Everything not within a timerange is 'production time'" do you mean if TimeStart and TimeFinished is null, and if so what does it mean if a result has a 'StopType' of 5 and non-null times?

Comment: This table contains only stops, not allowing nulls for TimeStart or TimeFinished. In this table 'Stops' there cannot be any rows with StopType = 5. I want to add these rows in my final result.

Comment: Ah I understand.  Where do the rows come from then?

Comment: I want to add them. The condition is that if there is a gap between two stops, this shall be added as production time, called StopType = 5. The production time is not registered anywhere. Not stop = production.

Comment: @Ivan I think I found a solution ;)

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1, S1.TimeFinished) AS TimeStart,
  (SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, -1, MIN(TimeStart)) FROM Stops WHERE TimeStart > S1.TimeFinished) AS TimeFinished,
  'PRODUKTION' as StopType
FROM Stops S1
LEFT JOIN Stops S2 on DATEADD(SECOND, 1, S1.TimeFinished) = S2.TimeStart
order by TimeStart